# How do I execute a Ruby script using VSCode?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

I'm using MacOS and I have installed VSCode, Ruby, rubocop, Ruby Solargraph, and their gem dependencies.

Having done this, how do I now execute a Ruby script without using the Terminal panel within VSCode?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like this? https://github.com/kortina/run-in-terminal

Comment: Press `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`P` and start typing `Ru`, you’ll see all the possibilities.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [Coder Runner Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).

Once adding the extension you press `Command + Shift + P` and select `run by language` then choose `ruby`

Comment: If you want to set up a key shortcut do: commant + shift + P, then look for "Run Code", click the gear icon and set whatever shortcut you want

Answer (score 17):

You have 2 choices for this case;

1. - Install `Code runner extension`
   - Then , `CTRL` + `ALT` + `N`

---

2. - Install `Code runner extension`
   - `Cmd` + `Shift` + `p`
   - choose `Run By language`
   - type `ruby`

wallla

Comment: another choice is to run a ruby file in the terminal. Just type `ruby name_file.rb`

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> after installing Coder Runner Extension

Answer (score 4):

You can try "Ruby Runner" extension for VS Code. It's works well in 2021.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MateuszDrewniak.ruby-runner

Answer (score 4):

## May 2023 update:

There are multiple ways:

### 1. Using tasks. The simplest and recommended way.

Add the following task to your project's `.vscode/tasks.json` file and then run it:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run ruby file",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "ruby ${file}",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": false,
                "clear": true
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

You might want to remap the `F5` key in `keybindings.json` to execute that task instead of the default behavior which fires a debugger. This is what I personally prefer to do.

```
{
    "key": "f5",
    "command": "-workbench.action.debug.start",
},
{
    "key": "f5",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Run ruby file", /* Label of the task defined above */
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'ruby'"
}
```

### 2. Using debugger (clumsier)

1. Install [Ruby LSP extension from Shopify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shopify.ruby-lsp) (`Shopify.ruby-lsp`).
2. Go to the "Debug" panel and click on the `create a launch.json file` link.
3. Run `Debug: Start Without Debugging` action.

The downside of this method is that it prints the additional information from a debugger.

> Ruby REPL: You can run any Ruby expression here. Note that output to
> the STDOUT/ERR printed on the TERMINAL. [experimental]   `,COMMAND`
> runs `COMMAND` debug command (ex: `,info`).   `,help` to list all
> debug commands. DEBUGGER: Disconnected.