# How do I run a ruby file in vscode terminal?

Tags: ruby, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So here is my problem. I have a folder with a lib and spec folder inside. I am trying to access a file inside my lib, named `part_1.rb`, and  run it but I don't know how to.

My code: (asterisk used to cover ubuntu name)

```
 *****:~$ ruby part_1.rb
 ruby: No such file or directory --part_1.rb (LoadError)
```

Comment: You need to give `ruby` the correct path to `part_1.rb`, which is relative to the current directory.  You can also `cd` where the `part_1.rb` is and run it with that command you have.

Comment: i tried running the same command after cd and got the same response No such file or directory... Also not to sure how to give the correct path I know this file 'part_1.rb' is inside my 'lib' folder but I don't know the command to access

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute a Ruby script using VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54917999/how-do-i-execute-a-ruby-script-using-vscode)

Answer (score 1):

try using: chmod +x part_1.rb and then execute via ./part_1.rb

Comment: I just tried this and I get chmod: cannot access 'part_1.rb' No such file or directory

Comment: What do you get when you do: nano part_1.rb

Comment: This is my first time running that command so what exactly are you looking for? Because I  ran the command and got GNU nano 4.8 part_1.rb

Comment: just making sure that part_1.rb and it's contents actually exists in the right path, so like using nano you will see the code in your terminal, so if the code gets displayed then there is no issue with the path or access to that file. So since you can only see GNU nano 4.8 part_1.rb and not the code for it, that means the path is incorrect. You should be able to see your code in terminal when you are in the correct path.

Comment: Oh thank you! I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

To check that the file is in your current directory, run `ls`.  This will print the contents of your current directory.

If the file is not in your current directory, but in your `lib` directory, you have two choices to run the file.

This will change your directory, then run the file.

```
cd lib
Ruby part_1.rb
```

This will search for the file in the subdirectory.

```
Ruby lib/part_1.rb
```