# How to configure VS Code to execute Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hi I am trying to configure VS Code under WSL to run Ruby code. I have already installed Ruby extension and VSCode Ruby in my VS Code. I also installed ruby from official page. But when I try to run `puts ("Hello world!!")` it doesn't execute and doesn't show output. Thanks for your answers and advices.

**EDIT** : My tasks.json file now looks like this

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "start",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "ruby ${file}",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

But there is still problem **`it won't build or even run my code`**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute a Ruby script using VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54917999/how-do-i-execute-a-ruby-script-using-vscode)

Answer (score 1):

You could configure a task and use the current file variable. Open `Tasks: Open Workspace Tasks` and than configure the following one in the tasks section:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "start",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "ruby ${file}",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        }
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
]
```

Most of the time I use the internal terminal to run my code. I create a bin file and execute my code.

Comment: Hi I just created new json file by configure default build task and paste there your code but I got  `End of file expected` and `Incorrect type. Expected "object"` I dontt know if it is what you ment

Comment: Seems like you replaced the whole file content with my code. You should only replace the tasks section in the file. Give it another try

Comment: I put it into json file but it didn't help. Or should I put it into same file as my test code `puts("Hello world!")` is?

Comment: What IDE do you use for Ruby if I may ask ?

Comment: VScode. But to run my code I mainly use shell commands directly

Comment: I instaled it on VS code too finally :) but is there way that it will highlight my syntax and show errors on certian lines like it does for other programming languages in VS code ?